# What exactly does the "web" tag mean?

Tags: discussion

I saw someone use the [web] tag ([Web browser that can view page source for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/564/web-browser-that-can-view-page-source-for-android)) . I think this tag is either a) too broad or b) needs a definition on proper use. Any thoughts?

Comment: ... And it looks like Robert has killed it. Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the [web](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) tag as it currently stands tag is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, and rhetorical and cannot be reasonably used.<sup>*</sup>

Therefor I think we should either:

- Burniate it
- Synonymize it with [web-browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser)
- Synonymize it with [web-application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-application)

<sup>*Man using that phrase felt good. I miss you NARQ!</sup>

Comment: Kill it. (By editing it out — you can't synonymize an ambiguous tag.)

Comment: @Gilles *edit suggested*.

Comment: I think we should just kill it to avoid any confusion between [web-browser] and [web-application]

Comment: I second the movement to kill it.

Comment: My only problem with this discussion is the distinctive lack of the word "Burninate."

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Better?

Comment: @Seth Brilliant. I already upvoted, but this made me happy :)